# Using residues to compute complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $\phi:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{\pm i,\pm 2i\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with
$\phi(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2+1)^2(z^2+4)}$.

> 1. How can I find
>      $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2+4)}dx$$
>      using $\phi$?
> 2. Can I use the function $\psi:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{\pm i,\pm 2i\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with
>      $\psi(z)=\frac{e^{-iz}}{(z^2+1)^2(z^2+4)}$ to compute the integral? Why/why not?

Thoughts:
1. I thought computing the residues of $i$ and $2i$ might be handy, but I'm not sure how to continue on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)} dx = 0$$

since the integrand is odd and the integral converges (absolutely). So:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)} dx + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)} dx \\ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)} dx$$

Let $R > 0$ be large enough and $\Gamma_R = \gamma_R \cup [-R,R]$, where $\gamma_R$ is the upper half semi-circle of center $0$ and radius $R$.

Using Residue theorem, compute $\int_{\Gamma_R} \phi$. Then, prove that $\int_{\gamma_R} \phi \to 0$.

Finally note that $\int_{\Gamma_R} \phi = \int_{\gamma_R} \phi + \int_{[-R,R]} \phi$ and that $\int_{[-R,R]} \phi = \int_{-R}^R  \frac{e^{ix}}{(x^2+1)^2(x^2 + 4)}dx$, which converges to your integral.

Comment: For question 2.  Using $e^{-iz}$ instead of $e^{iz}$ ... perhaps the integral on the upper semicircle would no longer go to zero.  But you could use the lower semicircle in that case.  And then be careful to use the poles in the lower half-plane.

Comment: And question 2?

Comment: @PhilCollins sorry, I did not pay attention to question 2. Anyway just see GEdgar's comment: you can, but you should take the lower half semi-circle instead. The point is that $|e^{-iz}| = e^y$, so to get the integral over $\gamma_R$ going to $0$, your $y$ should be negative - i.e. the $\gamma_R$ should lie in the lower half plane.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to Ahmed Hussein's one. If we consider, for any $\alpha >0$,
$$ I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}\,dx$$
we have:
$$ I''(\alpha)=-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2 \cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+1}\,dx = I(\alpha)$$
so $I(a)= k_1 e^{\alpha}+k_2 e^{-\alpha}$, and since $I(\alpha)\to 0$ as $\alpha\to +\infty$ by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and $I(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $I(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\alpha}$ and by parity:
$$ \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}, \qquad I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\,e^{-|\alpha|}.$$
We may recover the same formula by computing the Fourier transform of $e^{-|x|}$ by integration by parts, then applying Fourier inversion. At last we may notice that $$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+4}\right)$$
so, for any $\alpha >0$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} J(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)}&=&\frac{I(\alpha)}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2+4}\,dx\\ &=&\frac{I(\alpha)}{3}-\frac{I(2\alpha)}{6}\end{eqnarray*} $$
and:

> $$ \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{(x^2+1)(x^2+4)} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{6}\left(2 e^{-|\alpha|}-e^{-2|\alpha|}\right)}.$$